# Expectation under two equivalent probability measure

Tags: probability

For two probabilities, if they are equivalent, then does there exist a r. v such that the signs of its expectation under those two probabilities are different?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is just vague to the point of incoherence. Things that are "equivalent" cannot be "different". If they are equivalent the answer is no, if they are different the answer is yes

Comment: @DaleM "Equivalent" in "equivalent measures" refers to a quite specific notion.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. For a specific example, try the probability space $(0,1)$, one probability uniform, the other with density $\frac12+x$, and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ defined by $X(x)=x-c$ for various values of $c$.